# req.session object is not being created even after initialization in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, connect-mongo

**App.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const Mongo_connect = require("./mongo-config.js");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = require("./src/Router/route");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
// const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const app = express();
const mongo = async () => {
  await Mongo_connect(app);
};
mongo();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("../../Frontend/home/dist"));
// Remove this later
app.use("/api/v1/", router);

app.listen(3600, () => {
  console.log("Server listening to port 3600, ENJOY");
});

app.get("/info", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session);
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User");
module.exports=app;
```

**Mongoconfig.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const Mongo_connect = async (app) => {
  const uri =
    "#############################################";
  mongoose.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  const db = await mongoose.connection;
  db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Connection error:"));
  db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB...");

    const sessioninit = async () => {
      const sessionCollection = await mongoose.connection.db.collection(
        "sessions"
      );
      const mongoStore = await MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl:
          "############################################",
        collection: sessionCollection,
      });
      console.log("Mongostore intitalization done...");
      const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
      await app.use(
        session({
          secret: "070703",
          resave: true,
          saveUninitialized: true,
          store: mongoStore,
          // cookie: {
          //   maxAge: oneDay,
          //   secure: true,
          // },
        })
      );
      app.use(cookieParser());
    };
    sessioninit();
    console.log("Session created successfully...");
  });
};

module.exports = Mongo_connect;
```

**Main issue is the req.session object is undefined even after its initalization**

Whenever I try to set properties of req.session this error is obtained.
`TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'username')`

other key points are:

- Mongo connection is successfully established (I can store and retrieve data from the DB)
- Session collection is being successfully created in the DB.
- I don't think the session object is properly initialized.

Comment: Where do you try to set `username`? I don't see that in the code, which you posted.